# Should I use json objects directly?

Tags: android, json, parsing, standards, conventions

I have always used a ***fromJson*** method to convert my json object to my model object. So let's say that my JSON has a car field which has my car models data, so I always parse the Json. Now I found out that it's also a common practice to use the json objects directly in the application. That has gotten me thinking

> should I parse the json back to my models, if yes then why and if no then why not?

Answer (score 0):

It depends but in general - yes, you should have transformation logic to convert your jsons (essentially, DTOs) into your entities (models as you call them). Here is my reasoning:

1. Your entities will likely be different from corresponding DTOs. As an example, your json model can have date/time information as `long` UTC msecs, but your entity model will likely be more usable if it has localized `Date`'s
2. If you're exposing your entities (for example, as part of a library), you'll have much more flexibility in making changes to your remote apis (if such exist of course) without breaking your library's consumers codes

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on your project structure, if you have POJO classes defined in the models then converting them is the way to go. It makes your code more readable and fulfils your model which makes fetching the data easier. If you use a JSONObject directly then pulling data from it requires a bit more code. In terms of performance they both should have equal impacts since both are 'Objects' and will consume resources equally.

> I vote for parsing them back to Models because of the simplicity it
>   enables for using those values further in your coding.